# How to resolve extra forward slash added to angular route?

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, angular-routing

I'm using the angular-route library in Asp.Net Core to allow client side routing.
But when I hit the link to browse to the `editor` view I get the following with an extra `%2F`which isn't a valid route in the route provider:

http://localhost:57916/App/trips#!/#%2Feditor

Instead of the expected route which will work:

http://localhost:57916/App/trips#!/editor

I did look at the routeProvider config for this route and see that there is no extra forward slash in the .when check. Also angular-route is installed via Bower and matches my current angular version `1.6.1`:

```
$routeProvider.when("/editor",
```

**Question:**

Can anyone explain why an extra forward slash encoding is being added to the route?

The button which links to the editor view:

```
            <td><a href="#/editor" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">Manage</a></td>
```

This is the $routeProvider for the editor route:

```
   $routeProvider.when("/editor", {
        controller: "tripEditorController",
        controllerAs: "vm",
        templateUrl: "/views/tripEditorView.html"
    });
```

And the complete app-trips.js file which contains the routes. The first route works fine to the tripsView.html file:

```
//app-trips.js
(function () {

    "use strict";


    //Creating the module
    angular.module("app-trips", ["simpleControls", "ngRoute"])
    .config(function ($routeProvider) {

        $routeProvider.when("/", {
            controller: "tripsController",
            controllerAs: "vm",
            templateUrl: "/views/tripsView.html"
        });

        $routeProvider.when("/editor", {
            controller: "tripEditorController",
            controllerAs: "vm",
            templateUrl: "/views/tripEditorView.html"
        });

        $routeProvider.otherwise({ redirectTo: "/" });
    });

})();
```

Comment: missing the `!` in href

Comment: @charlietfl so like my first URL returned the href on the link shuould be? `<td><a href="#!/editor" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">Manage</a></td>`

Also why exactly is the `!` needed, is it to link to a different part of the same page?
`

Comment: only needed if you have declared using that hashbang

Comment: @charlietfl trial and error with the URL's I found this route works to browse to the editor view considering my current route config:   `<td><a href="trips#!/editor" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">Manage</a></td> `On the other hand trying the following routes in the link href didn't find the editor view `href="#!/editor"` or `href="#editor"` or `href="#!editor"`